# How to explain disparities in Flavonoid Docking results between Vina and Schrodinger?

Tags: docking

I am planning to dock a protein to [Selleck Chem's Flavonoid Library](https://www.selleckchem.com/screening/Flavonoid-Compound-Library.html). I have designed two workflows using Autodock Vina and Schrodinger as follows:

**Schrodinger**

- Use their proprietary tools for protein preparation followed by grid preparation under default settings.
- Run `LigPrep` on the SelleckChem library to generate one ligand (at most) per compound under default settings.

  - I executed another run (let's call it 'special run'; see below) generating eight ligands (at most) per compound under default settings.
- Run Glide in SP mode under default settings + add a reward for H-bonds.

**Autodock Vina**

- Run every module of UCSF Chimera's [Dock Prep](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/ContributedSoftware/dockprep/dockprep.html) on the Protein under default settings.

  - Except use Reduce in place of AddH - [suggested](https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/ContributedSoftware/addh/addh.html) by Chimera as a better alternative.
- Calculate grid-center to be the centroid of the default ligand and use the same grid size as used in Schrodinger workflow.
- Run `prepare_receptor4.py` but in non-default settings to only remove lone pairs and non-standard residues.

  - We do not remove waters or add charges, as done under default settings; they have been already executed by Chimera.
- Download 3D files of each compound in the Selleckchem library from Pubchem in `sdf` format.

  - Use Obabel to convert them to `pdb` format.
  - Run `prepare_ligand4.py` under default settings to get output in `pdbqt` format.
  - Use Obabel to replace Gasteigger charges with `eem2015ba`.
  - Use Obabel to minimize energy using `MMFF94` forcefield under default settings.
- Run Vina 1.2 to dock at `exhaustiveness` of `32`.

The results from the two workflows exhibit **vast disparity** with the correlation coefficient of the rank being about `0.2`. For example, the best result of Schrodinger is ranked 150 by Vina (the library has about 200 molecules in total) and so on. If I take the best 20 results from Vina and Schrodinger each, there is a single common compound.

In my 'special run', I saw that Schrodinger assigns vastly different overall docking scores to various conformations of the same ligand. This might answer the above disparity unless I am doing something acutely wrong. *But* that raises the question about how to choose the initial conformation of the ligand if I am constrained to use open-source software and starting conformations influence the final result so severely?

Comment: Please show the first few lines of results, or whatever other appropriate way can demonstrate this desparity.

Comment: @gringer I have added a couple of lines. Does this suffice?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I think that's enough.